# hosting .ejs file and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

How do you host multiple webpages with an extension file of .ejs? I have a login page coded in .ejs and I wanted to host it on node.js by using those .ejs file and other pages connected with the login page I have or rather I wanted the login.ejs file to run using node.js. Thank you very much

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://expressjs.com, especially at https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Put all your *.ejs files in views folder (recommended way) and then set them as views in express using following code

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Now you can start rendering them on the path you wanted like below

```
router.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
   res.render('foo') // this renders /views/foo.ejs
}
```